# Material-UI + Enzyme: Shallow Rendering components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm working on updating my app to the latest version of React, Enzyme and Material-UI.

I know that with version 15, Material-UI removed the default theme components would create if none was given. The preferred method now is to wrap the whole application with a `MuiThemeProvider` component with the style we want to use. This works without any hitch, but my tests now break when they shouldn't.

Any component that uses a Material-UI component and where I call `ShallowWrapper.html()`, will now make my tests fail with the message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined`.

Note that if I don't use `ShallowWrapper.html()`, I don't get any error. So it's only when I need to see the HTML output that it fails. Which makes sense, Material-UI should only care about style when actually render something.

I created a very simple test case to show how I'm doing it:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as chai from 'chai'
import chaiEnzyme = require('chai-enzyme')
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
let expect = chai.expect;

describe('Unit Test', () => {
    it(`Should work`, () => {
        let shallowComponent = shallow(
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Avatar src='foo.jpg' />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
        expect(shallowComponent.html()).to.exist
    })
});
```

I thought simply wrapping my component was supposed to work. Evidently, I'm missing a step somewhere. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Many thanks, I was absolutely stumped why my tests were failing with Material-ui and then I found the offending console.log(wrapper.html()) line, once I removed this the error you describe goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `mount` in this case, `shallow` only renders the component one level deep, so it will not render children that way, try this:

```
describe('Unit Test', () => {
    it(`Should work`, () => {
        let shallowComponent = mount(
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Avatar src='foo.jpg' />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
        expect(shallowComponent.html()).to.exist
    })
});
```

Comment: Seeing as I'm asking something impossible, I guess that makes this the answer! Going from this, does that mean Shallow stops being shallow as soon as `.html()` is called?

Comment: That's not exactly right, why don't you log it and see. Also take a look at .debug. you can get an idea of what you're testing

Comment: Ugh; this isn't ideal testing syntax. I hope we can rely less on this <MuiThemeProvider> wrapper for the future of the library.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I still don't understand. According to [these examples](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/html.html) in the official enzyme documentation for the `html()` method, it should be totally fine to call `shallowComponent.html()`. Why does this not work with the `MuiThemeProvider`? Could someone explain this for beginners?

Comment: It's because `shallow` will not render any children (that's the point), so it ends up testing `MuiThemeProvider` only, without testing the `Avatar` component. Ideally we should be shallow testing `Avatar` with the context from `MuiThemeProvider` present.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I gave a custom theme as the default theme to `makeStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  // theme object
}), { defaultTheme: customTheme });
```